# Why do I have to cast my array dimensions to int when I'm setting them with ints?

Tags: c++

I have a member pointer called Cells declared as:

```
Cells* cells;
```

In a member function I allocate some memory for cells like this:

```
void myClass::SetSize(int w, int h)
{
    cells = new Cells[w*h]; //gives a warning
}
```

The warning is: `C26451 Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '*' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '*' to avoid overflow.`

I've seen some people assert that this is a VS2019 bug and if so that's fine. But others insist this is correct and I can't figure out why. Why would it be necessary to do a cast here?

Comment: The point is that if you do a 4-byte multiplication it might overflow, even if the true number is representable in 8 bytes. Casting to 8 bytes **before** the multiplication happens avoids that possibility. Not that I would necessarily recommend doing it, it does depend on the situation.

Answer (score 4):

The [`new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) expression accepts a `std::size_t` which is an unsigned type. Passing `int`, which is a signed type, will require a type conversion. Depending on the size of `int` and `std::size_t` on your system, that may be a narrowing conversion.